# Can we start a sentence with ‘But’?

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

I’ve often come across articles saying we should not start a sentence with a conjunction. However, many many times have I seen a sentence starting with ‘But’. Isn’t But a conjunction? Or is it an exception? I’m very confused about what actually is the rule here. Please explain.

Comment: Generally, you should not do it. There are exceptions where it might make a sentence sound better, but don't let the exceptions define the norm.

Comment: Yes, but not your first sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But of course you can! It's quite common. It's not a hard rule, it's just a recommendation found in some (not all!) style guides for formal and professional writing. In everyday language it's perfectly normal and acceptable to begin a sentence with a conjunction.

Another commonly cited "rule" is to avoid ending a sentence with a preposition. This is also only a recommendation and nowadays almost always disregarded. This led to a famous quote, [often wrongly attributed to Winston Churchill](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/%7Emyl/languagelog/archives/001715.html):

> This is the type of arrant pedantry up with which I will not put!

Comment: Oh...Ok. Thanks for the insight. I’m a newbie so can’t upvote. **But** I’ll accept it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it sounds weird to begin a sentence with "but", except in the British idiom "but of course".

In cases where you would want to use "but" at the beginning of a sentence, "however" is usually a suitable replacement.   For example, in your comment on TypeIA's answer, I would have said "I'm a newbie so I can't upvote.  However, I'll accept it".

Comment: Oh. I get it now. So can I use ‘Yet’ as a replacement as well?

Comment: "Yet" is kind of archaic and sounds odd in today's English.  But I suppose it would work.

Comment: What about Nevertheless and nonetheless? I suppose those two are appropriate too?

Comment: Nevertheless and nonetheless are fine, although they're quite formal. In less formal writing/speech, "But" is probably better. Or you can use an adverb like "Still" or a phrase like "Even so".