# Is it ungrammatical to use "but" at the start of a sentence?

Tags: conjunctions

I often hear people start a sentence with "But".  I also find many books using a "but" at the start of a sentence.  My teacher, however, told me that it's ungrammatical and that I'm not supposed to use "but" at the start of a sentence especially in formal documents.

My teacher says, for example, that:

> A) Luffy was inspired to become a pirate.  **But** his life changed forever when he ate the magical fruit.

should be

> B) Luffy was inspired to become a pirate, **but** his life changed forever when he ate the magical fruit.

or

> C) Luffy was inspired to become a pirate.  **However**, his life changed forever when he ate the magical fruit.

Is it true that using "But" to start a sentence is ungrammatical and not accepted in formal documents?

Comment: This post might help: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52239/why-do-people-incorrectly-begin-a-sentence-with-the-word-but?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we start a sentence with ‘But’?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/284794/can-we-start-a-sentence-with-but)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do people, incorrectly, begin a sentence with the word "But"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52239/why-do-people-incorrectly-begin-a-sentence-with-the-word-but)